# Geometric Series of the form $ar^{n-1}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I just have a couple of general questions: is the $n$th term of a geometric series always of the form $ar^{n-1}$? or is it any sequence where there is a common ratio? Does it always help to re-write a problem in the form $ar^{n-1}$ or just write out the first few terms and find $a$ and $r$?

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: Did you mean to ask whether the $n$th term of a geometric sequence is always of the form $ar^{n - 1}$?

Comment: What is an example of a sequence where there is a common ratio, but the terms are not in the form $ar^{n-1}$?

Comment: If you were asked to find $\frac14+\frac18 +\frac1{16}+\frac1{32}+\frac1{64}$ you could quickly say this is $1-\frac12-\frac1{64}=\frac{31}{64}$ without finding $a=\frac14$ and $r=\frac12$ and $n=5$, so the answer to "does it *always* help?" may be "no"

Comment: You can figure it out if you try several problems! Experience in problem solving really helps.